# Convergence in Total Variation on a d-dimensional Torus

Tags: convergence-divergence, markov-chains, random-walk, total-variation

> Let $\mathbb T_k$ be a d-dimensional torus with sides of length $k$,
>   and let $S_n^{(k)}$ denote the lazy simple random walk on $\mathbb
>  T_k$ (which jumps to each of its neighbors with equal probability, and
>   does not jump with probability $\tfrac{1}{2}$), starting at the
>   origin. Denote \begin{equation} p_n^{(k)}(x) = \mathbb P\{S_n^{(k)} =
>  x\} \quad \text{for all}  \quad x \in \mathbb T_k, \quad k, n \in
>  \mathbb N,  \end{equation}Let $(t_k)$ be a sequence satisfying $t_k /
>  k^2 \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Let $\mu^{(k)}$ denote the uniform
>   distribution on $\mathbb T_k$.
>
> Prove that \begin{equation} \|p_{t_k}^{(k)} - \mu^{(k)}\|_\text{TV}
>  \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} 1. \end{equation}

Apart from the fact that $\mu^{(k)}$ is also the stationary distribution of the Markov Chain corresponding to the random walk, and that $p_{t_k}^{(k)}$ tends to be small for values far from the origin, I have literally no idea where to start, so any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, 'neighbors' as in the problem description deserves some clarification. The set of neighbors of a vertex here means the set of adjacent vertices viewed on the lattice in $(\mathbb Z/ k \mathbb Z)^d \cong \mathbb T_k$.

Comment: What is a "neighbor", precisely?  If $(1,1,0,\ldots,0)$ a neighbor  of $(0,0,0,,\ldots,0)$ ?  Is $(2,0,0,\ldots,0)$ a neighbor? How many neighbors does a typical point have?

Comment: I presume that OP means nearest-neighbor structure, but OP's clarification is always welcome. Anyway, in such case, note that $p^{(k)}_{t_k}$ is concentrated around the origin within distance $\asymp \sqrt{t_k} = o(k)$, which makes up only a negligible portion of $\mathbb{T}_k$ with respect to the uniform measure $\mu^{(k)}$ in the limit. I guess that a suitable concentration inequality (such as Hoeffding) would make this idea rigorous to show the desired limit.

Comment: Sangchul Lee's comment looks good to me.  I assume $d$ is fixed?

Comment: @SangchulLee That indeed seems like a good approach, but I am having trouble making it rigorous. I tried using the inequality $\mathbb P\{\max_{0 \leqslant m \leqslant n} |S_m^{(k)}| > s \sqrt n\} \leqslant 2d \exp(-\beta s^2)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N, s > 0$ for some $\beta > 0$ with $n = t_k$, but it did not lead anywhere. (The inequality is from Proposition 2.1.2 in Lawler and Limic, 2010, Random Walk: A Modern Introduction). The reason was I could not find a meaningful s in terms of k that yields a useful upper bound.

Comment: @kimchilover, $d$ is indeed fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think application of Sangchul's idea to your problem is easier than your comment indicates.  To show $\|P - Q\|_{\mathrm{TV}}$ is close to $1$ it suffices to exhibit an event $A$ for which $P(A)$ is close to $1$ and $Q(A)$ is close to $0$.   (Where $P$ is the law of $S^{(k)}_n$, and $Q$ is the uniform distribution.) In your case (unless I've made an algebra mistake somewhere), $A$ can be as simple as the first component of $S^{(k)}_n$ obeying $|S^{(k)}_n|\le \sqrt n \lambda$ where $\lambda$ will chosen later.

The first component of $S^{(k)}_n$ is a 1-d random walk with step distribution concentrated at $\pm1$ with probabilities $1/4d$ each, and on $0$ with prob. $1-1/2d$.  So its variance is $1/2d$.  $P$ concentrates its mass near $0$, and $Q$ spreads it out.  (There is a slight sloppiness here: the first component of 
$S^{(k)}_n$ is the mod $k$ reduction of an integer random variable with variance $n/2d$, and hence concentrated near the origin; modular reduction makes first component of $S^{(k)}_n$  even more concentrated near the mod $k$ origin.)

Then Chebyshev gives $P(A)\ge 1-1/(2d\lambda^2)$, and obviously $Q(A)\le(1+ 2\sqrt n\lambda)/k$. You want $n=(\epsilon_k k)^2$, where $\epsilon_k\to0$, so choice of $\lambda=1/\epsilon_n$ makes $P(A)\to 1$ and $Q(A)\to 0$.